# wpf update source on control leave

Tags: c#, wpf

The normal behavior of my textbox is to update the source when key is pressed.
But i need to validate the source property by query sql server.

My entity implement IDataErrorInfo

In this[prop]{} I check database for duplicate entries.

The problem is that check database each time a key is pressed. I would like to validate the property on control leave to reduce the number of db query.

The xaml of the textbox :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=RefFourn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" MaxLength="19"/>
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LostFocus on UpdateSourceTrigger

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=RefFourn, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue='', ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" MaxLength="19"/>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx